# Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp81\htdocs\test\inc\db.php on line 75

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I want to connect to oracle database, but i got this error :

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp81\htdocs\test\inc\db.php on line 75."

I already check php.ini file, and there are 2 lines :

```
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
```

I already remove the (;)

```
extension=php_oci8.dll ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
```

Then I restart the apache, but when I start the apache, I got an error:

> "error when start apache the procedure entry point OCIPing could not be located in the dynamic link library OCI.dll"

After that I try to login to my website, then i got an error:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp81\htdocs\test\inc\db.php on line 75"

Any solution for this case? I already tried to uncomment the `extension=php_oci8.dll` , but still have an error.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of XAMPP have you got installed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34494636/2125924

Answer (score 0):

you can also see this answer from this question

here is tutorial of installing oci8 drivers for PHP

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34494636/2125924